# Does Voice Over in a Xamarin.Forms app distinuguish between enabled and disabled buttons state on Android and iPhone?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, voiceover

I would expect the IsEnabled property on Buttons, and other controls to be used by Voice Over to distinguish between enabled/disabled states in Android and iOS. Is there some other property I need to use? Is this supported by Xamarin.Forms?

Answer (score 0):

When you set a button in xaml like

```
<StackLayout>
  <!-- Place new controls here -->
  <Button Text="Click"  />
</StackLayout>
```

### Android

If you set the `isEnable` as **True** or without setting it(the default value is True),The voice will only play the voice about text of **Button** (Click Button) .

When you set the `isEnable` as **False**,the voice will play the voice about text of **Button** and the `isEnable` is false (Click Button , disabled) .

### iOS

If test your app on simulator,you will get the following image by using **Accessibility Inspector** of Xcode .

[image]

You can get the states of `Enable` from **Traits** . And it is the same on real device .

So, of course it will distinuguish between enabled and disabled buttons state on Android and iOS.

Comment: The Voice over just reads out the text of the button and seems to ignore IsEnabled on Android?

Comment: Yes, if it will ignore it.But I thnk just like iOS ,we can get it by code.

Comment: I tried deploying (from VS) to a device, but XCode Accessibility Inspector doesn't pick up anything, it picks up the device but stays blank. I don't really get how I can use the Accessibility Inspector of Xcode to get Voice Over to read out disabled states correctly to the user?

Comment: Check https://www.raywenderlich.com/845-ios-accessibility-tutorial-getting-started.

Answer (score -1):

If setting `Enabled` properties in the native Android and iOS works fine for you, that is exactly what is being done by setting `IsEnabled` in Xamarin.Forms.